# The coding meaning of timerHasStarted= false

Tags: android, timer, countdowntimer

could anyone explain what is the meaning of 
-private boolean timerHasStarted =false;
and what does it function within the CountDownTimer coding?
and is it a must in a CountDownTimer implementation?

Answer (score 0):

`timerHasStarted` is a boolean(true/false) declared to identify whether a countdown timer has been started/ticking or not.

This is NOT a must in CountDownTimer implementation but may be required to keep a track of countdown timer activity in your application code.

```
 private Boolean timerHasStarted = false;
 CountDownTimer cdt = new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
         timerHasStarted = true;
         mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
    }

    public void onFinish() {
         timerHasStarted = false;
         mTextField.setText("done!");
    }
 }
 cdt.start();
```

Comment: hence am I right if i were to implement this code in the following way??   -public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) { 
   if (!timerHasStarted) {
    timerHasStarted = true;
    timer.start();
        //INACTIVITY=TRUE
     //ACTIVATE COUNTDOWN
    Log.v("Timer::","Started");
     
      }
   }

Comment: you can not start countdown timer in onTick(). It should be separate. Check code in link below:- [countdown timer android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html)

Comment: I have seen that they start the timer by "}.start()" at the end of both onTick() & onFinish(). But in my coding, I have implement "timer.start()"[onTick()] & "timer.cancel()"[onFinish()]. Hence, I would like to know how am I able to incorporate .start() and .cancel(), if I cannot code them within.